# Timelion Split on a substring of a field

Tags: elasticsearch, timelion

I would like to split my timelion chart on a substring of a particular field by using a regular explression. For example I have a field "URL"

mysite.com/doSomething1?user=2
mysite.com/doSomething1?user=1
mysite.com/doSomething1?user=1
mysite.com/doSomething2?user=4

I would like Timelion to consider only what is before the "?" before agregating the data

So I would get  
mysite.com/doSomething1 :3
mysite.com/doSomething2 : 1

instead of

mysite.com/doSomething1?user=2 : 1
mysite.com/doSomething1?user=1 : 2
mysite.com/doSomething2?user=4 : 1

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: No.. You can regex in the label of the field but not directly on the field itself